# How to display - Drop table status on Oracle Log file

Tags: oracle

I have the following on a script file followed by other scripts

```
DECLARE table_exist PLS_INTEGER;
 BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_exist FROM USER_TABLES WHERE table_name = 'SampleTable';

   IF table_exist = 1 THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SampleTable';
   END IF;

END;

.... other script commands .......
```

I want to know what is the result of the above statement. Currently I have a log file which captures all the script and its result. Since the above statement is not being terminated with a status like Table Dropped the subsequent script command is erroring out. How can this be avoided?

Comment: I added a "/" after the END; and it is now executing correctly. The log file displays "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." after this the subsequent script command is not erroring out.

Answer (score 1):

> "I added a "/" after the END; and it
>   is now executing correctly."

The slash is necessary to execute a SQL script.  So, you add the slash and the script executes, which leads the subsequent scripts to succeed.  Who'd a thunk it?

The main point being is, your process is wrong: dynamically dropping tables is a code smell.  It may be necessary in certain other RDBMS products but Oracle has lots of functionality. Tell us *your actual business requirement* and we can tell you a better way to achieve it.

Comment: I agree on your valid point. On the question I was asking since the above statement is not being terminated the subsequent command is erroring out. Sorry for not being clear. If you suggest not to use dynamic query what other ways can I check to see whether table exists?

Comment: @Kalis - the point is, not how to test whether the table exists but why you have a process which depends on dropping it.  DDL is not the sort of thing which should be run repeatedly.  Once ought to be enough.